# Python: Least squares with error on xdata

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I included the error on the ydata by using weights for my residuals. How can I implement an error on xdata? I hope I don't have to switch fitting routines, because I now use the lmfit package which is brilliant.

http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/

Comment: I don't know anything about this module, but would switching your x and y data, and repeating hat you've already done be too hacky and horrible?

Comment: What I'm trying to fit is a little bit too complicated to just switch...

Comment: Is it ok to just add the xerror to the weighting?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like orthogonal distance regression:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html